# Application logs an INSERT into database but data is not there. Where to look for debug info?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, php5, ubuntu-14.04, freetds

I have a PHP shell application which essentially moves data from a MySQL table to a REMOTE MS SQL Server (2008 R2) server based on a number of business rules.

This routine has been working flawlessly for the past 6 months but today data wasn't moved, BUT the application log registers it was.

I have made the following checks so far:
    LINUX END (runs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, MySQL 5.5.40, links to SQL via FreeTDS 0.91-5):
    1) Syslog;
    2) Auth.log (for eventual weird login attemps);
    3) Maillog (to track whether admin email was actually sent or might be fake);
    4) Security logs (we run security software to check if files have been tampered);
    5) PHP error log/Apache Error logs

WINDOWS END (runs Windows 2008/R2, SQL Server 2008 R2):
1) Event viewer (filtered ALL events within the time frame in question);
2) Table properties (to check for eventual changes/problems in the actual receiving table);

I am almost dismissing this as a network glitch, since further processing is working just fine, but since it's such a critical process I would like to be as thorough as possible.

Are there any other places to double check?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your application to test its error handling. It should not send a succes if the data has not been properly handled. Does it currently test if the inserts happened?

Comment: Do you have any checks built into your php script to verify that the data made it to mssql successfully?

Comment: Currently, we check if the INSERT returns OK and we only log in such event.  We don't actually SELECT from MSSQL to check if the data DID make it there, but it does begin to sound a good idea, since it seems the return code from TDS insert may not be 100% reliable.